# Is there a way to use a FormArray as the top level form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm using @ngular/core 6.1.1 and @angular/forms 6.1.1

I'm trying to write a ControlValueAccessor which will manage an array of values.

I'm using reactive forms and declaring my form like this:

```
export class ItemsFormComponent implements ControlValueAccor, OnInit {

    public form: FormArray;

    public items: string[] = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.array(this.items.map((item) => new FormControl(item)));

        this.form.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(200)
            .subscribe((items: string[]) => {
                this.onChangeFn(items);
            });
    }
}
```

But then, I get a Template parsing error with

```
<ol [formArray]="form">
    ...
</ol>
```

`Can't bind to 'formArray' since it isn't a known property of 'ol'`

I DID include the FormsModule and the ReactiveFormsModule in my Feature Module. Any other form based on FormGroup work.

It kinda works if I do `<ol [formGroup]="form">` but it seems like a weird hack and the validation seems broken. And I'm afraid it will break when building for prod anyway.

So is there no way to use a FormArray as the top level form? Ideally, I'd like to avoid creating a FormGroup with a single FormArray in it.

Comment: "It kinda works if I do <ol [formGroup]="form"> but it seems like a weird hack and the validation seems broken. And I'm afraid it will break when building for prod anyway." Why? For me is correct

Comment: OK, it builds in prod with `<ol [formGroup]="form">` but it still looks like a hack to me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use FormArray as the top level form,

```
place: FormArray = new FormArray([
      new FormControl('SF'),
      new FormControl('NY'),
]);
```

And in the template,

```
<div *ngFor="let c of place.controls; index as i">
  <input [formControl]="c" placeholder="c">
</div>

<ng-container *ngFor="let c of place.controls">
  <pre>{{this.c.value | json}}</pre>
</ng-container>
```

Here is the working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgkbos?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) on stackblitz

Comment: I disagree, you are treating `FormArray` as a regular `FormControl[]` array. This is not how the top-level control should be treated. I just can't find answer anywhere so I will assume 'No' on this one.

Comment: My answer is based on the question asked. What's wrong to have a formArray as a top level form?